# Connect Motorola SE3300 imager (part of barcode scanner) to Raspberry PI 2

Tags: camera

I am reading documentation and can not figure out if I will be able to connect module SE3300 (Motorola imager) to Raspberry PI 2. Either through camera port (CSI-2, 15 way S5 connector S5) or throught any gpio ports.

The imager has 21 line ZIF connector, 8 data lines, i2c lines, however other are custom

[image]

this comes from [integration guide](http://www.quad.de/WebRoot/quad/Shops/qios/MediaGallery/Dokumentation_OEM/SE3300IG_Rev8.pdf) page 39.

CSI-2 MIPI interface is described [MIPI page](http://mipi.org/specifications/camera-interface) and [MIPI CSI-2 spec](http://electronix.ru/forum/index.php?act=Attach&type=post&id=67362) It has also 8 data lines and also i2c lines, but that is all.

Are those devices compatible? Will I be able to read from the camera using available drivers?

In the SE3300 integration guide I can see that it uses Aptina MT9V022 (mono) Wide VGA CMOS Digital Image Sensor. In the linux source code I can see it has drivers for it.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/media/i2c/soc_camera/mt9v022.c

Can anyone connect the dots for me or point out problems?